# Recursion in python to find odd positions in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

Recall that the positions in a list of length n are 0,1,…,n-1. We want to write a function oddpositions(l) that returns the elements at the odd positions in l. In other words, the function should return the list [l[1],l[3],...]. For instance oddpositions([]) == [], oddpositions([7]) == [], oddpositions([8,11,8]) == [11] and oddpositions([19,3,44,44,3,19]) == [3,44,19]. A recursive definition of oddpositions is given below. You have to fill in the missing argument for the recursive call.

```
def oddpositions(l):
  if len(l) <= 1:
    return([])
  else:
    return(...)
```

examples:
oddpositions([8,11,8]) must produce [11]

Comment: For a list `l` you can do `l[1::2]`.

Comment: thank you for the answer it worked for my case

Comment: @a_guest How is that recursive?

Comment: @schwobaseggl It's how you should solve that problem in Python. If you really like you can think of it having recursion depth zero :-)

Comment: well it is not but i could not get the answer previously , from your method I was able to get an evaluation

Answer (score 0):

The following will do:

```
def oddpositions(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [] 
    else:
        return [lst[1]] + oddpositions(lst[2:])

>>> oddpositions([])
[]
>>> oddpositions([7])
[]
>>> oddpositions([8,11,8])
[11]
>>> oddpositions([19,3,44,44,3,19])
[3, 44, 19]
```

Comment: Why not use `return list[1:-2:2] + oddpositions(lst[-2:])` instead? That's also recursive and much more efficient :-) For example try `oddpositions(list(range(1_000_000)))`.

Comment: I see what you did there :) but that's fake recursion, why not `return list[1::2] + oddpositions([])` in the first place :P Of course, if someone is going for performance, they will not go for recursion at all.